# how to get calendar event update on android device

Tags: android

I want to get calendar event updates (when a new event is added or an existing event is deleted ) on android 2.2 devices ? 
i am beginner so tell me step by step solution for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you :)

```
public class myCalendar 
{

static Cursor cursor;

public static void readCalendar(Context context) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the
    // user has them selected for display.


    cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected"}), null, null, null);


    HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Count="+cursor.getCount());
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("the control is just inside of the cursor.count loop");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

             String _id = cursor.getString(0);
             String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
             Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

            System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
            calendarIds.add(_id);
        }
    }
    }
    catch(AssertionError ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // For each calendar, display all the events from the previous week to the end of next week.        
    for (String id : calendarIds) {
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
        //Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars").buildUpon();
        long now = new Date().getTime();

        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 10000);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 10000);

        Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                new String[]  { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1,
                null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");

        System.out.println("eventCursor count="+eventCursor.getCount());
        if(eventCursor.getCount()>0)
        {

            eventCursor.moveToFirst();

            while (eventCursor.moveToNext())
            {
                Object beg_date,beg_time,end_date,end_time;  

                final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
                final Date begin = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(1));
                final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
                final Boolean allDay = !eventCursor.getString(3).equals("0");

        /*  System.out.println("Title: " + title + " Begin: " + begin + " End: " + end +
                    " All Day: " + allDay);
        */  
                System.out.println("Title:"+title);
                System.out.println("Begin:"+begin);
                System.out.println("End:"+end);
                System.out.println("All Day:"+allDay);

                System.out.println("only date begin of events="+begin.getDate());
                System.out.println("only begin time of events="+begin.getHours() + ":" +begin.getMinutes() + ":" +begin.getSeconds());

                System.out.println("only date begin of events="+end.getDate());
                System.out.println("only begin time of events="+end.getHours() + ":" +end.getMinutes() + ":" +end.getSeconds());

                beg_date = begin.getDate();
                beg_time = begin.getHours()+":"+begin.getMinutes();

                end_date = end.getDate();
                end_time = end.getHours()+":"+end.getMinutes();





            }
        }
        break;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: using this code can i know which event is update and delete from android device..

Comment: You can do further modifications to it..currently it just fetches events from google calendar:)

Comment: this is not support android jelly bean please give me guide line or content uri name.